# requireCheckbox method signature meaning on the DataValidationBuilder class

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Unfortunately, the Apps Script [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) about `DataValidation` builder is missing information about the `requireCheckbox` method.

When you type it in via a script file, though, autocompletion offers 3 overloads:

no args:

```
requireCheckbox()
```

1 arg:

```
requireCheckbox(Object checkedValue)
```

2 args:

```
requireCheckbox(Object checkedValue, Object uncheckedValue)
```

What parameters of an object can I use in these arguments and what purposes they may serve?

Answer (score 6):

`CHECKBOX` cell by default, has two values:

- `TRUE`, when checked and
- `FALSE` when unchecked.

Depending on the number of arguments provided to requireCheckbox,  different values are used:

- No argument:

  - The default values are used.
- One argument:

  - The provided argument, when checked
  - Blank, when unchecked
- Two arguments:

  - The provided arguments are used for checked and unchecked states respectively.

#### Sample code:

```
function yesNoDV() {
  //Changes checked state to 'Yes'  and Unchecked state to 'No'
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getRange('Sheet1!A1')
    .setDataValidation(
      SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireCheckbox('Yes', 'No')
        .build()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the default type Google's documentation uses when more specific types do not apply. You can safely interpret it as an analog for `any` (and in fact, the `@types` TypeScript package for Google Apps Script has those parameters annotated with `any`).

Also, as of 2021, [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirecheckbox) has information on all method overloads. To quote from it, the overloads function is as follows.

**No arguments**

> Sets the data validation rule to require that the input is a boolean value; this value is rendered as a checkbox.

**One argument**

> Sets the data validation rule to require that the input is the specified value or blank. When the input matches the specified value the cell is rendered as a checked checkbox. When the input is blank the cell is rendered as an unchecked checkbox.

**Two arguments**

> Sets the data validation rule to require that the input is one of the specified values. When the input is checkedValue the cell is rendered as a checked checkbox. When the input is uncheckedValue the cell is rendered as an unchecked checkbox.

The meaning of each overload hasn't changed from that outlined in [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486501/11407695).